# Editing questions which are on hold

Tags: discussion, editing

Is it worth it to try and edit questions which are on hold or should people assume that the moderators are working on them?  Is the answer the same regardless of how long ago the question was asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question is on hold, editing it would be of big value for us. Only a few moderators are taking the time to edit them. Most times the question is on hold, because the moderators saw no way to improve it.

So yes, please edit the question, even if it is a very old one.

Comment: Especially for questions which are on hold for being unclear or off topic we (moderators) *need* for OP to edit, as we would just be guessing as to the intent.